# Trim NSString to specific pathComponent

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an NSString which represents paths like

```
.../App/Some/Directory/myClass.mm
```

Now I want to trim

```
.../App/Some/Directory/
```

to get only the Class' name/file. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your string to a NSURL, and the get the lastPathComponent to get the "myClass.mm" you want.

```
NSString* filePath = @"/App/Some/Directory/myClass.mm";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
NSString* lastComponent = [url lastPathComponent];
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: You don't even have to convert to NSURL, because NSString has a `lastPathComponent` method as well.

Comment: It does! I was not aware of that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the string into components (using the `/` as the separator), and then the filename will be the last element of the output array.

```
NSString *input = @".../App/Some/Directory/myClass.mm";
NSArray *array = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSLog( @"%@", [array lastObject] );
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString class has lastPathComponent method, also you can solve your problem like this:

```
NSString *path;
NSString *trimmed;
NSRange range = [path rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    trimmed = [path substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
else
    trimmed = path;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* str = @"/App/Some/Directory/myClass.mm";

NSRange replaceRange = [str rangeOfString:@"/myClass.mm"];
if (replaceRange.location != NSNotFound){
    NSString* result = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"Result :%@",result);
}
```